# Unexpected control flow while using "On Error GoTo" , compare it with "Try.... Catch"

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

Both `"Try.... Catch`" and "`On Error GoTo`" are exception handling mechanisms in VB.NET. then what are the difference between them?

What are the reasons for the following?

1. a block will allow multiple `try..catch` or multiple `On Error GoTo` but `not both` will allowed in the same block.
2. for the following code:

   ```
   Private Sub check_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles check.Click

       On Error GoTo l1
       On Error GoTo l2
       rt.LoadFile("e:\new\me.txt")
       l1:TextBox1.Text = "Not found"    
       l2:TextBox1.Text = "Not found"
   End Sub
   ```

   why `l2` is executed before `l1` executes, if the path is not found?

Answer (score 5):

The `On Error GoTo` construct is only kept for legacy code. The only reason that it exists at all in later versions of VB is to make it easier to use old (but tested and working) code with minimal changes.

There is no reason ever to mix the old type of error handling with exception handling. Newly written code should not use the old error handling. Mixing them has been disallowed in the compiler on purpose.

When you use `On Error GoTo` each setting will replace the previous, so only the last setting will be active.